# vue webpack build for publishing library

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I'm building a vue application starting from this [template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack).
 Now that I wrote some components I would like to publish them in the npm registry in order to be able to import them in another project, just like any other npm library. The problem is that running

```
npm run build
```

output many .css/.map/.js files.
What I would like to achive is an output like mylibrary.min.js that I can import eventually doing something like:

```
npm install myLibrary --registry myregistry
```

and after that:

```
import myLib from "mylibrary";
```

or

```
import Component1 from "mylibrary/lib/myLibrary.min.js";
```

There's a way to do that? What's the best practice in this case? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Check out the webpack config file from the webpack-simple template.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the part of your question where you want to create single files.

Create a copy of `webpack.prod.conf.js` and name it `webpack.npm.conf.js`. Essentially, this has all the parts related to creating chunks commented out and replaced by single file references. Here's mine:

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const env = require('../config/prod.env')

const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true,
      usePostCSS: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? config.build.devtool : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/bundle.js'),
    // filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    // chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        compress: {
          warnings: false
        }
      },
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      parallel: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/bundle.css'),
      // filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css'),
      // Setting the following option to `false` will not extract CSS from codesplit chunks.
      // Their CSS will instead be inserted dynamically with style-loader when the codesplit chunk has been loaded by webpack.
      // It's currently set to `true` because we are seeing that sourcemaps are included in the codesplit bundle as well when it's `false`,
      // increasing file size: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/1110
      // allChunks: true,
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: config.build.productionSourceMap
        ? { safe: true, map: { inline: false } }
        : { safe: true }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      // chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    // new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // enable scope hoisting
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: 'vendor',
    //   minChunks (module) {
    //     // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
    //     return (
    //       module.resource &&
    //       /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
    //       module.resource.indexOf(
    //         path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
    //       ) === 0
    //     )
    //   }
    // }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: 'manifest',
    //   minChunks: Infinity
    // }),
    // This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
    // in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
    // see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
    // new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    //   name: 'app',
    //   async: 'vendor-async',
    //   children: true,
    //   minChunks: 3
    // }),

    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  const CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

This will create only two files for your bundles named `bundle.js` and `bundle.css`.

Then go to the `build` folder and make a copy of `build.js`, naming it `build.npm.js`. Modify line 12 so it uses your `webpack.npm.conf.js`:

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.npm.conf')
```

Last, open your `package.json` and go to the `scripts` section and add the following line:

```
"build-npm": "node build/build-npm.js"
```

Now you can create the build type you want using

```
npm run build-npm
```

Comment: Does this still work? I think I may have to adjust a ‘nuxt’ Webpack config to get it to export my components as a library and not an overall app. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jujubes I cannot answer that question. I dropped Vue.js in favor of native web components 2 1/2 years ago.